androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialUnsupportedException: Your device doesn't support credential manager
I am trying to implement Google sign-in in Android using Credential Manager using the below documentation
Authenticate users with Sign in with Google
Below are the code snippet
    val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)

    //Generating temporary Nonce
    val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
    val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    val digest = md.digest(bytes)
    val hashedNonce = digest.fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }

    val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
        .setNonce(hashedNonce)
        .build()

    val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
        .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
        .build()

    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                request = request,
                context = this@AuthActivity,
            )
            val credential = result.credential

            val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)

            val idToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
            Log.d(TAG, "signIn: $googleIdTokenCredential")


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString())
        }
    }

While running this code on two different devices, I am getting different error messages: Below are the device's basic details with their error message.
Realme 11 pro+ 5G with Android version 14
androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialUnsupportedException: Your device doesn't support credential manager

Redmi 9 power with Android version 12
androidx.credentials.exceptions.NoCredentialException: During begin sign in, failure response from one tap: 16: [28433] Cannot find a matching credential.

How to resolve these errors, Can someone please help me with this?
and The same piece of code will work on every device or not. I need help on that as well.
